# Create button on Firefox toolbar to execute JS

Tags: javascript, firefox, customization

I need the toolbar button to execute my custom JavaScript code in Firefox. 
Currently I just copy-paste this JS into console, but it is annoying.
What is the best way to create such button?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but .. `<span onClick="myFunction();" ?>My Button</span>` ?

Comment: @brod I need that button on the toolbar in my Firefox

Comment: oh! my bad - no idea..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet.

Example - create a shortcut to any site on in your browser and replace the URL address with similar code:

```
javascript:(function(){ alert('Hello!'); })();
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer put me in right way to find this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20390382/2089491.
Bookmarklet should return undefined to avoid redirect to new page. It can be achieved by end the function without `return`. But as I used some jQuery funtions, I managed to use the second way: put `void(0)` as last operation of my code. Could you please extend your answer with this information.

Comment: While it's possible to use a series of statements terminated with `undefined` value (`void(0)` evaluates to it), I do not recommend it.

With anonymous functions you can define variables without polluting global scope :)